# Automatic toggle between 3 elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to toggle between 3 different elements, but script that I am using toggle only between 2 first and when is visible the second one, it's covered by the third one in the same time. How should I edit my function to toggle between 3? JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/uktszzwp/

Thank you!

SCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var continuous = function() {
    $("#citat1").fadeToggle(700);
    $("#citat2").fadeToggle(700);
    $("#citat3").fadeToggle(700);    
}

setInterval(continuous,4000);
 </script>
```

Comment: Can you put this in a fiddle or show the html atleast?

Comment: @ajmajmajma here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uktszzwp/ ... there it's not even working.. no idea why..

Comment: Ok, what exactly do you mean toggle between 3? Like 1 at a time? Or all 3 at once

Comment: @ajmajmajma When the page loads, `#citat1` should be visible. After 4 seconds it should toggle to second div and after next 4 seconds to the third one. And after next 4 seconds again on first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it.  I'm just cycling through the numbers 1, 2 & 3, then `fadeIn()` the element that matches and `fadeOut()` the other two:

```
n = 0;
var continuous = function() {
  n++;
  if (n > 3) n = 1;
  for (k = 1; k <= 3; k++) {
    if (k != n) {
      $("#citat" + k).fadeOut(700);
    } else {
      $("#citat" + k).fadeIn(700);
    }
  }
}

setInterval(continuous, 4000);
```